# Can't connect mongodb after ubuntu-precise server restart

Tags: python, mongodb, ubuntu-12.04, scrapy

I am developing a web scraping project on Ubuntu server of 25GB hard disk space. I am using python scrapy and mongodb

---

Last night my harddisk is full because of scraping 60,000 web pages. so mongodb has put a lock and i am unable to access my database it shows this error

```
function (){ return db.getCollectionNames(); }
Execute failed:exception: Can't take a write lock while out of disk space
```

So i removed all data stored in /var/lib/mongodb and run "rebbot" command from shell to restart server

When I try to run mongo on command line, I get this error:

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.5
connecting to: test
Thu Jul 25 15:06:29.323 JavaScript execution failed: Error: couldn't connect to
server 127.0.0.1:27017 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:L112
exception: connect failed
```

Guys please help me so that i can connect to mongodb

Comment: I have also tried removing mongod.lock file from var/lib/mongodb

Comment: Is MongoDB definetley running and listening? `ps aux | grep mongo` and `netstat -an | grep ':27017'`

Comment: when i run this commands service mongodb restart  It shows   Stop: Unknown instance
mongodb start/running, process 3759

Comment: @JoeDoherty what i should with this command ps aux | grep mongo and netstat -an | grep ':27017'

Comment: You run it on the command line.

Comment: mongodb is running i have checked it by running this command ps aux | grep mongo

Comment: You have removed the mongo lock but can mongo write to that folder? also check to see if u can `telnet localhost 27017` that should connect if it is running.

Comment: hey guys i have uninstalled mongodb. Re-installed mongodb to solve my problem but still i am unable to connect mongodb. How should i clean mongodb files

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is to find out whether MongoDB is actually running. You can do that by running the following commands on the shell:

```
ps aux | grep mongo
```

And:

```
netstat -an | grep ':27017'
```

If neither of those has any output, then MongoDB is not running.

The best way to find out why it doesn't start is to look in the log file that MongoDB creates. It is usually located at /var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log and it should tell you why MongoDB refuses to start.

Comment: You didn't do the netstat - add that output to your question.

Comment: please add the output to your question